# Getting POST 500 Internal server error while sending request via ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a logic where I want to insert data into database. SO I am sending `ajax` request through my local machine. Below is the code for the same..

```js
$("#btnSubmitCT").on('click', function () {       

        var valid = validateForm();
        if (valid) {
            $("#divLoadingPanel").show();
            SubmitForm_CE().done(function () {
                $("#divLoadingPanel").hide();
            });
        }

    });
    
    
function SubmitForm_CE() {
    try {

        var req_id = "";
        var umsGroupNameBy = CurrentGroupName;
        var umsGroupIdBy = CurrentGroupID;
        var loginUserName = LoginUserName;
        var spanType = $(spantypeid + ' option:selected').val().toUpperCase();
        var r4gState = $(r4gstatediv + ' option:selected').text();
        var UG_LEN = parseFloat($('#UGLEGCE_txt').html()).toFixed(4);
        var AR_LEN = parseFloat($('#ARLEGCE_txt').html()).toFixed(4);

        var fixedUG = parseFloat($('#UGLEGCE_txt').html()).toFixed(4);
        var fixedAR = parseFloat($('#ARLEGCE_txt').html()).toFixed(4);

        var linkId;
        var spanId;
        var createdId;
        if (spanType == AppConfig.SpanTypeInter.toUpperCase()) {
            linkId = "";
            spanId = $(spnLinkId).text();
            createdId = "SPAN ID: " + spanId;
        }
        else {
            spanId = "";
            linkId = $(spnLinkId).text();
            createdId = "LINK ID: " + linkId;
        }

        var mZoneCode = $(mzoneid + ' option:selected').val();
        var mZoneText = $(mzoneid + ' option:selected').text();
        var mZoneArr = mZoneText.split('/');
        var mZoneName = mZoneArr[0];
        var operationType = $(activitytypeid + ' option:selected').val().toUpperCase();

        var pendSpanLeg = parseFloat($(pendingSpanLen).html());
        var neLeg = parseFloat($(spnspanlength).html());        
        var offerHoto = parseFloat($(hotoofferbyct).val());
        var offerDate = $('#ctOfferdatepicker').val();
        
        var remark = $(remarkct).val();
        var offerValue = JSON.stringify({ "OFFERHOTO": offerHoto, "OFFERLIT": "0", "NE_LEG": neLeg, "HOTOCOMPLETED": "0", "LITCOMPLETED": "0" });
        var statusId = getHotoStatusID(offerValue);
        var umsGroupObj = JSON.parse(UMSGroupDetails)
        var GroupToValue = "";
        var umsGroupNameTo = "";
        var umsGroupIdTo;
        $.each(umsGroupObj, function (index, element) {
            if (element.GroupName == UserGrouop.FE) {
                umsGroupNameTo = element.GroupName;
                umsGroupIdTo = element.GroupID;
            }
        });
        var Values = { "SPANID": spanId, "LINKID": linkId, "CREATEDBY": loginUserName, "MZONECODE": mZoneCode, "MZONENAME": mZoneName, "NELEG": neLeg, "UGLEG": UG_LEN, "ARLEG": AR_LEN, "STATUSID": statusId, "HOTOOFFERDATE": offerDate, "REMARK": remark, "HOTOOFFERLEG": offerHoto, "UMSGROUPIDBY": umsGroupIdBy, "UMSGROUPNAMEBY": umsGroupNameBy, "UMSGROUPIDTO": umsGroupIdTo, "UMSGROUPNAMETO": umsGroupNameTo, "SPANTYPE": spanType, "R4GState": r4gState };

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: AppConfig.PrefixURL + "App/InitiateWF_CT",
            data: JSON.stringify(Values),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            //            async: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                var datalist = JSON.parse(response);
                var state = datalist.split('|')[0];
                var msg = "";
                if (state == "SUCCESS") {
                    msg = "Request Id: " + datalist.split('|')[1] + " has been created for " + createdId;
                    req_id = datalist.split('|')[1];                    
                    hideInfoWindow();                    
                    hideLoading();
                    jAlert(msg, ValidationMessageConfig.Title, function () {
                        $(spandetailsdiv).hide();
                        deleteSpanListDatatable_CT($(spnLinkId).text());
                    });

                } else if (state == "WARNING" || state == "EXISTS") {
                    msg = datalist.split('|')[1];
                    hideInfoWindow();
                    hideLoading();
                    jAlert(msg, ValidationMessageConfig.Title, function () {
                        $(spandetailsdiv).hide();
                        deleteSpanListDatatable_CT($(spnLinkId).text());
                    });
                } else {
                    hideLoading();
                    msg = datalist.split('|')[1]
                    jAlert(msg, ValidationMessageConfig.Title, function () {
                        $(spandetailsdiv).hide();
                        deleteSpanListDatatable_CT($(spnLinkId).text());
                    });
                    AppLog.getLogger('error', "Error occured during processing new job");
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
               // jAlert(ErrorMessageForMethods.initiateWF, ErrorMessageForMethods.Title);
                //AppLog.getLogger('error', "Error occured during processing new job");
                // hideLoading();
                alert('NO Record created 1');
                hideLoading();
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        $(spandetailsdiv).hide();
        hideLoading();
        alert('NO Record created 2');
        //jAlert(ErrorMessageForMethods.initiateWF, ErrorMessageForMethods.Title);
        //AppLog.getLogger('error', "Error occured during processing new job");

    }
}
```

`url: AppConfig.PrefixURL + "App/InitiateWF_CT",` here it is telling that **http://localhost:2126/App/InitiateWF_CT 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Can you suggest what is wrong in this ?

Comment: something on the server

Comment: @DaveNewton: where exactly? on DB part ?

Comment: Check the server logs

Comment: @Akib: how can I check it ? i m doing this on my local machine

Comment: Determining the cause of a 500 Internal Server Error response code requires investigating the server logs for error messages. These logs typically provide insights into the specific issue that caused the server to return the 500 response.

Comment: To check the logs you should have access of the server

Comment: I can’t begin to guess “exactly”. I see “Internal Server Error” and many lines of mostly-unrelated client code. You need to check the server. If you can’t, compare the request on the wire with server expectations.

Comment: First of all, note that stackoverflow is not your personal army that helps you solve your own troubles. Stackoverflow is a Q&A website, it's first purpose is to help delevopers share their knowledge, not to solve everyday problems. If your question is about backend rather than frontend then add information about backend logic and expected behaviour

Answer (score -2):

There clearly not enough information to say what's causing that 500 error:

- 500 error indicates that it's an **unexpected** error on the server side. It means (if the server is implemented correctly) that it has nothing to do with the request itself; for invalid requests 4xx error should be sent;
- We don't have (and you're not sharing) any knowledge about the server.

I would recommend you following steps:

1. Run the request manually (you can use tools like Postman, HTTP Client or REST Client extensions for VS Code, cURL, etc). This way you'll eliminate client and will be able to quickly try different request options and see what exactly server returns; depending on the access level you have to the server, you can leverage logs / debug the server / enable more detailed error reporting;
2. Once you'll find the correct request format, you can come back to the client to find a way to follow identified format.